# Windows Firewall blocking port 443 despite rule opening it (after router upgrade)

Tags: https, router

For years my iPhone has loaded pages from a dev web server on my home PC (e.g. via https://192.168.1.154). I just got a new router (FIOS) and can load pages from my iPhone via http (port 80) but loading a page via https (port 443) just hangs. Both work from a browser on the PC.

It looks like a firewall issue because it works if I turn off the Windows Firewall. But adding a firewall rule to allow incoming connections on 443 doesn't help, and I didn't need one before.

Dropped packets from firewall log file look like:

```
date time action protocol src-ip dst-ip src-port dst-port size tcpflags tcpsyn tcpack tcpwin icmptype icmpcode info path

2023-01-22 10:53:55 DROP TCP 192.168.1.153 192.168.1.154 55441 443 64 S 3009098762 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding the firewall rule for the correct network profile? Different rulesets apply depending on whether your new LAN network is being recognized as "Public" vs "Private" (or "Domain").

Answer (score 1):

Turns out another firewall rule was blocking access. Sorting the rules by "Action" to put "Block" at the top showed it -- two rules called "Node.js JavaScript runtime" were blocking all inbound ports. Disabling them fixed the problem. No clue how the router change might have been involved.

Comment: If issue was resolved by this answer then please accept the answer (even if question and answer were both your own).

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, I will but they make you wait 2 days :-)

Comment: Ahhh! You mean SuperUser?